Probability density function on the interval with floating endpoint
We have a random variable  $L$  and we know that:
$$
l = \begin{cases}
    x \cdot \sec(\theta) & \text{for } 0 < \theta < \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), \\
    \csc(\theta) & \text{for } \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \leq \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}.\end{cases}$$
In addition, we know that $X\sim U(0,1)$  and $\theta\sim U(0,\pi/2)$ are independent variables.
The problem is to find the density function for the random variable $L$.
Attempt: Using transformation of random variables and vectors I found the density for $L$ on intervals $(0,\pi/4)$ and $(\pi/4,\pi/2)$ and it came out as follows:
$$
f(l) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{4}{\pi} & \text{for } 0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{4}, 0 < l < 1\\
    \frac{4}{\pi l \sqrt{l^2 - 1}} & \text{for } \frac{\pi}{4} \leq \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}, 0 < l <\sqrt{2} .\end{cases}$$
But I have no idea how I should transform $L$ when one point of interval contains random variable, as mentioned above (arctan(1/x)).

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Are $X$ and $\theta$ independent? Please share what you have done so far.

@user408858 Yes, they are independent and I added my result so far.
